# Set font size equal to an integer?

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

In **Swift**, I have a line that says `var timerFontSize = 85`. I want to have the line `timerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Ultralight", size: timerFontSize)`, although that doesn't work. It only allows me to type in a number, not assign it to a variable. The reason I don't want to just type in a number is because I have a timer, where every second the font variable drops by 1.

**How can I set the font size equal to an integer?**

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24230940/2792531

Comment: @nhgrif Cool, only saw the cast version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply type cast the number to CGFloat

```
UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Ultralight", size: CGFloat(timerFontSize))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this line:

```
var timerFontSize = 85
```

You're setting your variable implicitly to type `Int`, while the method for creating a font takes a `CGFloat` argument.

You could cast this variable as a `CGFloat` when you call the method, or you could explicitly create the variable as a `CGFloat` type:

```
var timerFontSize: CGFloat = 85
```

---

It's worth noting that

```
var timerFontSize = 85.0
```

Creates `timerFontSize` as a double, and

```
var timerFontSize = 85.0f
```

creates `timerFontSize` as a float.

The former will work for 64-bit devices where `CGFloat` ends up being a double, and the latter will work for 32-bit devices where `CGFloat` ends up being a float.  But you don't want to use either of these options as it will crash on the other device.

`CGFloat` is a typedef for `float`/`double` depending on whether the device is 32 or 64 bit processor.